# How to send variable value in send command of expect script

Tags: expect

Below is my script

```
proc sendline {line} { send -- "$line\r" }

set slot 1
set port 1
for {set x 0} {$x<48} {incr x} {
   sendline {curl -X POST -d '{"command":"dumpcommand","slot": "$slot","port": "$port"}' http://127.0.0.1:7777/api/test}

   expect -exact "OK"
   sleep 2
   incr slot
   incr port
}
```

I want slot and port to be replaced with 1 ,2 ....e.g

```
curl -X POST -d '{"command":"dumpcommand","slot": "1","port": "1"}' http://127.0.0.1:7777/api/test
```

Answer (score 0):

Braces in Tcl act like single quotes in the shell: they prevent variable substitition: see http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm

You need

```
sendline "curl -X POST -d '{\"command\":\"dumpcommand\",\"slot\": \"$slot\",\"port\": \"$port\"}' http://127.0.0.1:7777/api/test"
```

If all the escaped quotes are problematic, use `format` which is Tcl's printf equivalent

```
sendline [format {curl -X POST -d '{"command":"dumpcommand","slot": "%s","port": "%s"}' http://127.0.0.1:7777/api/test} $slot $port]
```

Comment: To clarify, in Tcl (and thus in Expect), {}'s _**prevent**_ variable and command substitution/expansion. You will need to use double quotes (") to allow variable expansion (and proper backslash (\) escaping of anything you do not want expanded), or use the format command to avoid "escape-hell".